# Migrating from Rails 2.3.11 to Rails 3.0.11: Now unable to use find with a collection of AR records

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm In the process of migrating from Rails 2.3.11 to Rails 3.1.3 and I am now on Rails 3.0.11 and sorting out all the issues that this brings.

The first one I can't solve is: in Rails 2.3.11, I could do the following and get the required records back

```
@event_type_time_units = TimeUnit.find(@event.event_type.time_units)
```

In Rails 3.0.11, I've tried using

```
@event_type_time_units = TimeUnit.find_with_ids(@event.event_type.time_units)
```

and

```
@event_type_time_units = TimeUnit.find_some(@event.event_type.time_units)
```

The code for both of those doesn't do anything magical and I expected them not to work.

Does anyone have a pointer for me, please.

Thank you

```
edit: the error I get is TypeError in MeetingsController#create

Cannot visit TimeUnit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails 3 uses `Arel` aka relational algebra to fetch associations. Assuming your `EventType` model has an association to `has_many :time_units`, you can just do the following:

```
@event_type_time_units = @event.event_type.time_units
```

Furthermore, you can optimize your queries using `EventType` as a join model (ish):

```
# app/models/event.rb
belongs_to :event_type
has_many :time_units, :through => :event_type

# app/models/event_type.rb
has_many :events
has_many :time_units
```

Now, you can query directly, saving a SQL call:

```
@event_time_units = @event.time_units
```

In short, there's no reason to do a find on an association. The association returns an "Array" of the records. (I use "Array" in quotes, because it's not *really* an array, but an `ActiveRecord::Association` which behaves much like an array)

### Aside

I highly recommend just migrating to Rails 3.1.3. It's just as difficult to migrate from Rails 2 -> 3 as 3 => 3.1. Save yourself the middle headache. In fact, given the legacy of your application, I recommend the following:

1. Create a new, empty Rails 3.1.3 application
2. Copy all your models, views, controllers, and libs to this new application
3. Search your existing projects for gems -> add them to your `Gemfile`
4. Review everything in `config/*`. This is where a LOT of changes have take place. If you have application-specific code in your existing application, port it over to the new one. Otherwise, leave it alone.

Comment: I think the reason for the downvote is because you misunderstood what I am trying to do. Based on the ids from event_type.time_units, I want to retrieve the relevant records from TimeUnit (as TimeUnit contains the information I need to display). TimeUnit.find(@event.event_type.time_units.map {|r| r.id}) fixes it but that's not the point of my post. As for your Aside, I was thinking of doing that, too. Thank you for replying anyway.

Comment: God, I'm such a knob. And no, I haven't been thinking of this problem all day, I've been busy with other things. And I realised that my code was rubbish and I was just doing the something twice. Must've been an early bit of Rails for me and didn't bother to see what it was doing while trying to resolve the problem. Have an upvote for just pointing out the obvious. What a knob I am!!